# Is there any way to get intersection type of generic rest parameters?

Tags: typescript

I write a merge function that merge multi objects and return.

```
type A = { a: number };
type B = { b: number };
type C = { c: number };

const a: A = { a: 1 };
const b: B = { b: 2 };
const c: C = { c: 3 };

function merge<T extends any[]>(...args: T): { [k in keyof T]: T[k] } {
    return args.reduce((previous, current) => {
        return Object.assign(previous, current);
    });
}

const m = merge(a, b, c);

m.a;
m.b;
m.c;
```

What I expect for type of `m` is `A & B & C`, but I got `[A, B, C]` in compiler, and it give me the error.

```
Property 'a' does not exist on type '[A, B, C]'.ts(2339)
```

Is there a right way to declare the return type of my merge function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the elements of the array:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAkgO2BOBnCBjYASwHs0AeAFSggA9M0ATbKOCRB0gGxCgFc0A1mmIB3NAG0AugD4oAXihVa9JlHGE0AMyxQAEmwYAaKADozG7XCgAlCNmCSoAfgCwAKCh6DUAGSwEyOiYOPhEpGS29tLungBcfILCYgDc7u6a-AQkaFAAtlgA5tCU1HQQjMys7Fw8iGggUtIAFGYmiHAF2PEUAJTx8EioGFi4WeEUsgDeMSwQwLxwOe2dJqwMvHgQTU1grABuJLzYxngLrBg98lMznqzzi1AA8gBGAFahbdjYhAVoO-uHY5QU4IcrAHqpDxQAC+EPc0LSblAkFg8igkygiHiaF4uWeOmhkOR0AAQmiMc9sbj8VZCe5iVAAMLk4FUvEEyHuBj4TjtaB4Uj2TH9SHcvC81jAwXAKCUqAk0U8vlStBCvDxRmctwC1Uy3Jo-IdLaIYzPE4QqAAektqL8ZL8jMRuTayStNpx7Lg7mdz1d1qgHpp3pMeD97upWER-pJEBEyuAAAtEDKNMFRkQ0AUoMTmCJCImpblcqQoLtiJA4EQ7FARAnCHgE1Ak3toBoBbkwMnCM9ONAczXCJxOLNsLxOCmcmgIC24LFEWKJfzpSOx8B+gEhmnQtkyOIZhisVB7HANFnoYZ97K2TSYReoRiK9hSPEMZpCDg10fgCfMzDb5fH2fdEoF5ex4mPU8-3PS85Qg39oLcGQtVYUdxxMQC0DDYC3w-cDv1PV1QM-OCCldBE3BQ1cXTdL8fwKdxKLQ30aKnGd3CAA)

```ts
type ArrayIntersection<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest] ?
  Head & ArrayIntersection<Rest>
  : unknown;

function merge <T extends readonly any[]>(...args: T): ArrayIntersection<T> {
  return args.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return Object.assign(previous, current);
  });
}

type A = { a: number };
type B = { b: number };
type C = { c: number };

declare const a: A;
declare const b: B;
declare const c: C;

const m = merge(a, b, c); // A & B & C

m.a; // number
m.b; // number
m.c; // number
```

Note that intersecting types which are incompatible (or have members whose types are incompatible) will result in `never` for that type:

```ts
declare const result: ArrayIntersection<[
  { a: string },
  { b: number },
  { person: { first: string } },
  { person: { last: string } },
  { b: string },
]>;

result.person; // { first: string; last: string; }
result.a; // string
result.b; // never
```

Comment: That's a clever way to do an intersection of array like type.

Comment: @AlexWayne I'm _pretty sure_ I discovered that recursive technique in one of [Aleksey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l)'s answers. (But I'm not sure which one, or I'd definitely link to it.)

Comment: Thanks! I like this recursive grammar, it inspires me more ideas!

Answer (score 1):

`T[number]` will produce a union of the types in the `args` array, and then you can use a [Union to Instersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to merge the members of that union into an intersection:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

function merge<T extends any[]>(...args: T): UnionToIntersection<T[number]> {
    return args.reduce((previous, current) => {
        return Object.assign(previous, current);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwG4BYAKFEigCEFkoDNdCTzq7xoAwixQBjDviKlKtWiID2WAM7A0mOIhQYoARh6yFytpmYajUAEx6a8pSrFQhp+wGYrtetACqWAJYKAKnIAkljAJIoQIsB+WAA8ngB8LLRQUAAUnlAQAB5hWAAmimhYIFAA-OkA1pieAJTwCQBucj75UBwQjSS1WbkQBUVpadVQPlgAZtxB9U0t+T0VQe3YnSQyNOM4WFExUHgkAOYQsf69eYXFIADaALoJaQB0T6jEB4qY-rU1vgHBoeGRaIKE5XTiSO7IFKpKDECDAHDELBoV6KB6w-I4EQQIZgWGNPw4RQAGigIgRsNCPQakJo0LpMLhCKRAHkCAArQEPVCKRQ+A5YNK4zoE4mk8n9YC1Xh0shS2hkdY2Qx4Fj7V7Y1AkggkkRymi0PBc3iGgjGh4iChAA)

Comment: I read the linked answer that you copied the utility type from, but I still don't understand how it works. Can you break it down step by step?

Comment: Alas, I cannot. It's something about converting a type from a covariant to contravariant position, which changes how the union is considered. Or perhaps vice versa? If @jcalz says it's "evil magic" you can probably take it for granted that it works. You can probably learn some advanced stuff by diving into it though, to which I say "good luck!"

Comment: Note that `const oops = merge(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: "a" } : { b: "b" }, { c: "c" })` will produce `never` with a straight union-to-intersection,  since this approach doesn't distinguish between unions arising from multiple elements and those already present in a single element.

Comment: @jsejcksn yeah it's a bunch of type juggling (similar to my answer here also). When you `infer` a single type from multiple types in a normal *covariant* type position you get a union. But if the types are in a *contravariant* type position you get an intersections. (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types )Functions are  contravariant in their parameter types (e.g., a union of functions can only accept an *intersection* of the parameters in order to be type safe), and gives us what we want. I hit the character limi

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! This is the work I did to explore for myself before you explained: https://tsplay.dev/w6Xlvm

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will take a note of this type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-recursive way to get an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all the elements of a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), you can do it like this:

```
type TupleToIntersection<T extends readonly any[]> =
    { [N in keyof T]: (x: T[N]) => void }[number] extends
    (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

It works via some type juggling that is easier to write than to explain (but I'll try):  First we [map the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `T` to a new version where each element at numeric index `N` (that is, `T[N]`) has been placed in a [contravariant position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) (as the parameter to a function, `(x: T[N]) => void`), and then [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that tuple with `number` to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those functions.  From this we  [use conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to infer a single function parameter type for that union of functions, which (as mentioned in the [linked doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)) produces an intersection `I`.

Whether that makes sense or not, you can observe that it works:

```
type ABC = TupleToIntersection<[A, B, C]>
// type ABC = A & B & C

type AorBandC = TupleToIntersection<[A | B, C]>
// type AorBandC = (A | B) & C
```

Note that the compiler preserves that `A | B` union in the second example.

---

Anyway that means we can write the output of `merge()` as `TupleToIntersection<T>`:

```
function merge<T extends any[]>(...args: T): TupleToIntersection<T> {
    return args.reduce((previous, current) => {
        return Object.assign(previous, current);
    });
}
```

And it produces the expected output:

```
const m = merge(a, b, c);
// const m: A & B & C
m.a;
m.b;
m.c;

const m2 = merge(Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b, c)
// const m2: (A | B) & C
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwG4BYAKFEigCEFkoDNdCTzq7xoAwixQBjDviKlKtWiID2WAM7A0mOIhQYoARh6yFytpmYajUAEx6a8pSrFQhp+wGYrtetAAqOMABsInnIAkljAJIoQIsAAlgoAPJ5QEAAeYVgAJopQxBCo6Qq+IGhYIADaALoAfAi0UHWspQByUNFYUADWECByAGZQnuWYABTJmJ5N5QCUCNUAbnLR6eSlnJLlSakQGYq19SOYrT3cQdPwcwtLAPxQQVAcELMkvO78sIyO-T7+gSFhxBFRWJYOKlGAAGiYEIEVVoAHpYVAPG8PnAAGRMKDogQyPgMGByYiMVAZD7ePwBYKhcKRGLxUFQAA+kIcMJo8MRr3xhOJ6Q+QzgTMY0yxOJ6OCwgIUUDwJAA5hAEhs0plimUqkMAHRa1DEWWKMaTMZfCm-amS4GeapIXZ1HLAHDENo6vUanLpHAiCBDIZgHKzWI4RQQkQOnKhU5Wm31W0Qe2OqAAeQIACsaRrUIpFNFZVgfX6A0GoCHiGHgJNeNGyOXaGQcTZDHgWDLdV7UBCCMHq2yEfWVHg1JiMSKaHh07xRwRxxqRM9rAY+5ZEM35UMALKoYAAC1dPLkeCG0ziUAADBqAKxQa6oO5sTtwnvz6XmYYCpjChxAA)

Comment: Thanks! Now I learn something about contravariant!